# Selecting range of month in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, select

How can I select the range of month with the variation of years?
for example, I have this in my table:

- Transportation | 2500| March| 10 | 2018
- Transportation | 2550| April| 10 | 2018
- Transportation | 2000| May| 10 | 2018
- Transportation | 3100| March| 10 | 2019
- Transportation | 1500| April| 10 | 2019
- Transportation | 2000| May | 10 | 2019

Ignoring the date,how can I select the months with variation of years. I want it to be selected like this:

- March | 2018
- April | 2018
- May | 2018
- March | 2019
- April | 2019
- May | 2019

all months should be included but it is just for example if the months are repeated again but with a different year..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select sum( `fair`) `fair`, `mon`,  `year` 
from table1 
group by `mon`,  `year`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e355f1/2)